# Adding a background gradient to existing background image with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background

I am stuck with a problem that has me baffled for hours now. Here is the gist of it:

I have a div that has a background image already set and I want to add a background gradient with a background blend mode of multiply.
This is so that when a person uploads a background image, it will automatically be rendered with the gradient above and no Photoshop is required to add it manually.

Right now I am at this point:

- I get the current background image url and store it in a variable
- I set the css with jquery to add that background image url and add a gradient (that is always the same)

Sounds simple enough, but it does not want to add my second gradient on that background.

Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var bg = $(".dnd_area-row-4-background-image").css("background-image")
bg = bg.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '')
$('.dnd_area-row-4-background-image').css('background-image', 'url(' + bg+ ')','linear-gradient', '(322deg, rgba(229,27,81,1) 0%, rgba(245,126,32,1) 100%);');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qh028wf1/

Would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Working Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yhde4xfa/

Your jquery of setting css background is wrong. The correct syntax should be;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bg = $(".dnd_area-row-4-background-image").css("background-image")
    bg = bg.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '')
    $('.dnd_area-row-4-background-image').css(
        'background-image', 
        'linear-gradient(322deg, rgba(229,27,81,1) 0%, rgba(245,126,32,1) 100%), url('+bg+')'
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the correction! Any ideas on how I can add an "!important" tag to this? I am working in Hubspot that applies a background image through its modules and also sets it as important, which overrides what the code provided wants to do. Not sure if adding an important tag to this might override what hubspot does. Here is a screenshot of the dev tools: https://prnt.sc/1172ixi

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @yeyene, good stuff that lead me to the actual solution that overrides any other styles.
Posting below for posterity:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bg = $(".dnd_area-row-4-background-image").css("background-image")
    bg = bg.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '')
    $('.dnd_area-row-4-background-image').css(
        "cssText", "background-image: linear-gradient(322deg, rgba(229,27,81,1) 0%, rgba(245,126,32,1) 100%), url("+bg+")!important"
    );
  
});
```

This adds the css with the !important tag, which I am aware cannot be done through json like in the last version of this code.
I appreciate your answer and the great community here for beginners!

Comment: Yes, you can treat js css string part as the same as css.